# Partitioning hint for custom RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark

`JDBCRDD` is potentially partitioned for efficient query parallelization on the database.

Is there a way to carry over *how* the data is partitioned as a useful hint to the next stage, potentially a `groupBy`, without having to repartition the data?

Example: I am loading date/region/value. With `JDBCRDD` I am loading the data partitioned by Date. If I want to reduce/groupBy date and region, I should again not cause a sort and shuffle for date, and leverage the fact that the RDD is already partitioning by date.

In a pseudo API, I would do something as follows:

```
RDD rdd = new JDCBCRDD ...
Partitioner partitioning = (Row r)->p(r)
rdd.assertPartitioning(partitioning);
RDD<Pair<Key,Row>> rdd2 = rdd.groupWithinPartition((r)->f(r),Rowoperator::sum);
```

So now in theory, all my groupings are to be executed JVM instance local, same node, same JVM, same thread.

Comment: groupBy is a wide dependency operation, can not use partition information.

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is need to keep the info of the **partition index** with each element, I think [mapWith](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#mapWith(scala.Function1,%20boolean,%20scala.Function2,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) is what you need. You can group the partition index with the data into a new class and pass to the next stage.

Comment: I have clarified what I attempted to do in the original question

Comment: I guess what needs to happen first is that a partition index needs to be defined first. Also note that JDBCRDD is actually a subtype of a RDD<Row>. It seems to me that indexing etc is intended for pairs (K/V).

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is controlled by the hash value of the elements in the RDD. To avoid shuffling going into the next stage, you basically need to guarantee that the same hash value is being generated. You do this by overriding the  [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) method.